# Exception Handling in Case Statement VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In the below method when we have case 'Else', it should throw an exception but for some reason the exception is not being logged at all. Can you point me to any problem in the code written below?  Can we catch an exception inside the Select and Case statement?

```
  Private Sub Country(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        mColumnName = "BORR1_MAILCOUNTRY_CD"
        Dim errmsg As String = String.Empty

        If Row.outBORR1MAILTOADDRSUBPROP = "Y" Then
            ' Property country is a manual-entry field and can have junk
            Dim outCountry As String = String.Empty
            Dim inCountry As String = GetSafeParsedString(Row.inPROPCOUNTRY)
            inCountry = inCountry.Replace(".", String.Empty)
            inCountry = inCountry.Replace(" ", String.Empty)
            inCountry = inCountry.ToUpper()

            Select Case GetSafeParsedString(inCountry)
                Case "USA"
                    outCountry = "US"
                Case "US"
                    outCountry = "US"
                Case "UNITED STATES"
                    outCountry = "US"
                Case "MEXICO"
                    outCountry = "MX"
                Case "MX"
                    outCountry = "MX"
                Case "CANADA"
                    outCountry = "CA"
                Case "CA"
                    outCountry = "CA"
                Case "CAN"
                    outCountry = "CA"
                Case String.Empty
                    outCountry = String.Empty
                Case Else
                    errmsg = String.Format("Can not map country.MailToSubProp is 'Y' but property country was input as  {0}", inCountry)
                    Throw New Exception(errmsg)
                    Return
            End Select

        END IF 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you step through the code with the debugger?  Does it execute that `Throw` line?  If so, you should be able to follow the execution to see where the exception is being caught.

Comment: Where are you _catching_ the whole exception...?

Comment: You don't need the `Return` statement behind the `Throw`, but other than that this looks like it should be ok. If it's not doing what you expect, then I'd say either your `Try/Catch` outside of this method is incorrect or you are never experience an `Else` condition.

Comment: content of GetSafeParsedString ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to catch the exception otherwise there is no need to throw the exception in the first place

```
 Case Else
        errmsg = String.Format("Can not map country.MailToSubProp is 'Y' but property country was input as  {0}", inCountry)
     Try
        Throw New Exception(errmsg)
     Catch ex As Exception
         'Log exception here
     End Catch
 End Select
```

Comment: so you had the chance to look at the "specification" of the program that he is building?

Comment: may be the exception are automatically logged when thrown.... there is no enough information

Comment: Why bother with the try/catch and throw in the middle? Just call the logging function. My guess is OP already has some built in parent method performing a Try/Catch or health monitoring that is expected to handle this already.